# How do I reduce the amount of SQL created by entity Framework?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have the following piece of Linq To EF...

```
    private IQueryable<VRTSystem> GetObjectSetWithIncludes() {
        return GetObjectSet()
          .Include(s => s.Site.Address.GeographicalLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation)
          .Include(s => s.Dhr.Select(d => d.DhrParts.Select(dp => dp.PhysicalPart.PartDefinition)))
          .Include(s => s.Room.RoomType)
          .Include(s => s.ProductConfiguration.ProductConfigurations_PriceBook.Select(pcpb => pcpb.PriceBook))
          .Include(s => s.ProductConfiguration.Quote_ProductConfigurations)
          .Include(s => s.ProductConfigurationTemplate)
          .Include(s => s.Customer.GeographicalLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation)
          .Include(s => s.Customer.CustomerType)
          .Include(s => s.HospitalGroupCustomer.GeographicalLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation)
          .Include(s => s.HospitalGroupCustomer.CustomerType)
          .Include(s => s.ServiceCoverHistories.Select(sch => sch.ServiceCoverLevel))
          .Include(s => s.SystemStatus)
          .Include(s => s.ShippingContact.Address)
          .Include(s => s.Quote)
          .Include(s => s.PaidDate)
          .Include(s => s.VRTSystemProductConfigurations
            .Select(
              spc =>
                spc.ProductConfigurationTemplate.ProductConfigurations_PriceBook.Select(
                  pcpb => pcpb.PriceBook)))
          .Include(s => s.VRTSystemProductConfigurations
            .Select(spc => spc.PaidDate))
          .Include(s => s.Quote_ProductConfigurations
            .Select(spc => spc.ProductConfiguration))
          .Include(s => s.ProductConfigurationTemplate
            .ProductConfigurationOptions.Select(pco => pco.ProductConfigurationOptionValues))
          .Include(s => s.SystemProductConfigurationOptionsSelectedValues)
          .Include(s => s.VRTSystemProductConfigurations
            .Select(spc => spc.UpgradeProductConfigurationOptionsSelectedValues));
    }
}
```

Lazy loading is switched off, as we are sending the results out over WCF, and so need all the data loading right away. Also, the WPF window that will be using the data needs all of those related tables.

This has been working fine for ages, but suddenly started throwing an exception that there were too many tables in the query. I looked at the SQL that was generated, and it was almost 20,000 lines, and did over 600 joins! I'm not surprised it threw an exception with that amount of SQL!

I'm really not sure why it does so many joins, given that the query is not referencing anywhere near that number of tables.

Any ideas why this may have suddenly started throwing this exception, and what I can do to improve this query? I realise that the best answer may be to do some major rewriting to split this down into smaller queries, but apart from the complexity of doing that, I need a quick fix, as the deployed system no longer works, and we need to get it running again urgently.

Comment: I'd consider breaking that up. Use eager loading for part of the data and separate explicit loading calls to fill out the rest of the object graph with smaller queries. Determining exactly how to break it up would require knowledge of the data model and likely some trial and error. I'd also reconsider whether the whole object graph needs to be returned from one WCF call or if there are parts of the data that can loaded on demand with separate calls.

Comment: Yeah, I'd already thought of that, but the problem is that the whole object graph gets sent up to the client as-is, and is bound to a fairly complex WPF window. Breaking it up would require a lot of hacking to stick the smaller bits together. What I'm bothered about is why this has suddenly happened. The query has been working fine for a long time. The same thing popped up today on a completely separate piece of code that had a much simpler query. I can't understand why it's suddenly generating SQL that throws an exception, when it's been working fine for so long.

Comment: Hmm, same issue just popped up in yet another area of the code, this time in one with quite a simple Linq query. If I have to start breaking down even simple Linq queries, I might as well not bother with Entity Framework in the first place. Something weird is going on here. We haven't changed the code, but queries that were working are now not. I would love to know why.